# I have a question about std::priority_queue

Tags: stl, queue, priority-queue

```
struct Event
{
    int ObjectID{};
    EnumOp Op{};
    high_resolution_clock::time_point WakeUpTime{};
    int TargetID{};

    constexpr bool operator>(const Event& rhs) const
    {
        return WakeUpTime > rhs.WakeUpTime;
    }
};

priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, greater<Event>> TimerQueue;
```

The default sorting method for priority queues is less. It actually sorts in ascending order, but is top returning the last element? Or is it sorting in descending order, despite being less, so top returns the first element?

Answer (score 0):

`top` returns the highest ranked element (i.e, the one with the highest priority). And yes, by default it uses `operator <`

Note that the elements in the underlying container are not sorted. They are *ordered*, but not in ascending (or descending) order.

Comment: So you're saying it's sorted? Are you saying no? What I'm curious about is why it doesn't look like sort in ascending order, even though the default is less.

Comment: "the elements in the underlying container are not sorted" - I don't think I can be any  clearer than that.